# FIWARE Orion: use query string in subscription payload

Tags: fiware-orion

Currently the '=' sign is forbidden in Orion:
http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/user/forbidden_characters/index.html

But this prevents to make a subscription with a query string:

```
$ (curl broker.waziup.io/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service:waziup' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath:/TEST' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "SensingDevice",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Sensor1"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "temperature"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost/v1/sms/send?contact=0039&msg=Sensor1",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "temperature"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

Results in:

```
{
    "subscribeError": {
        "errorCode": {
            "code": "400",
            "details": "Illegal value for JSON field",
            "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request"
        }
    }
}
```

The query string is used to pass parameters to the callback server (I don't see other ways to do it).
Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of setting query parameters in the notification URL, based in custom notifications in NGSIv2. Have a look to "Custom Notifications" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/).

The subscription you are doing would be something like this:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions
...

{
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Sensor1",
        "type": "SensingDevice"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ "temperature" ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "httpCustom": {
      "url": "http://localhost/v1/sms/send",
      "qs": {
        "contact": "0039",
        "msg": "Sensor1"
      }
    },
    "attrs": [ "temperature"]
  },
  "expires": "2016-05-07T18:30:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 1
}
```

Note that you could even generalize the subscriptions for all your sensors using templates, in the following way:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions
...

{
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "Sensor.*",
        "type": "SensingDevice"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ "temperature" ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "httpCustom": {
      "url": "http://localhost/v1/sms/send",
      "qs": {
        "contact": "0039",
        "msg": "${id}"
      }
    },
    "attrs": [ "temperature"]
  },
  "expires": "2016-05-07T18:30:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 1
}
```